# Synology DSM - DS Get from remote access

Tags: synology, dsm

I can't connect from remote access (4G) to `DS Get` (or `DS File`) to my Synology with a private domain.

For information, I can connect to the main dashboard with a navigator and access to Download Manager. And I can use `DS File` or `DS Get` when I am on my local network.

Is it possible to use `DS Get` from remote access with a private domain or did I have to create a `Quickconnect ID` ?

Comment: For information, I didn't find a way to use my custom domain and I ended to create and use a Quickconnect ID.